# Pergunta sobre "->"

Tags: php, mysqli

Bom dia, eu tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_email . "';";
            $query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
```

db_connection seria: `$this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);`

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, a variável `$query_check_user_name` recebe a variável db_connection pra a instância atual que recebe query($sql)?

Como que isso ficaria sem os "->"? E com o "->" como que funciona o processo? (quem recebe quem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ele irá receber o retorno do método `query()`. Simplesmente isso.

Depende do escopo da sua classe, se este método é retorno `__toString` ou etc.

É possível fazer retorno da instãncia da classe ao dar `return $this` no método invocado.

Eu não entendi muito bem a dúvida para ser sincero, ficou pouco mal formatada. Mas o que entendi respondi.

Ao invocar

`$query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->query($sql);`

Você basicamente esta dizendo:

PHP, tudo bom?

Preciso que você acesse objeto `db_connection` dessa classe, neste objeto terá outra instãncia, nessa instãncia você vai invocar o método `query` e informar `$sql`como argumento. O retorno de `query()` você armazena para mim na variável `$query_check_user_name` por favor.

Comment: Desculpe por ter ficado mal formatada.. Mas era exatamente isto que eu estava precisando! Obrigado Junior, esclareceu completamente a minha dúvida.

Comment: @rasec fico feliz de ter respondido. Precisando só voltar aqui.